# Query attendees outside your organisation

Tags: query, einstein-activity-capture

I am trying to somehow programmatically fetch the attendees of an Event that was synced via Einstein Activity Capture.
The attendees we are interested in are the ones that have not been synced to Salesforce but are displayed as "attendees outside your organisation".
You can view these attendees within the Event but I can't seem to find a way to query them.